# Rborist version 0.1-17 keeps crashing R session in windows

Tags: r

I was looking for a quantile regression forest package that allows the control of monotonic decreases/increases of the dependent variable for chosen IVs (see option regMono below). Unfortunately, my code always/quite often crashes my R session in Windows (version 3.6.1). I furnished this example/reproducible code, which for me always crashes the R session:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(Rborist)
library(datasets)

set.seed(42)

data(iris)

temp <- iris %>%
    select(
        Sepal.Width
        , Petal.Length
        , Petal.Width
        , Sepal.Length
    )

x <- subset(temp, select = -c(Sepal.Length))

model <- Rborist(x
    , temp$Sepal.Length
    #, quantVec = seq(0.1, 1.0, by = 0.1)
    , quantiles = TRUE
    , minNode = 5
    , regMono = c
    (
        -1.0, 0.0, 0.0
    )
)

prediction <- predict(model, x, quantVec = seq(0.6))
temp$prediction <- prediction$yPred
temp$residuals <- temp$Sepal.Length - temp$prediction

ggplot(temp, aes(x = prediction, y = adjusted_damages_paid_100)) +
    geom_point(color = "black")
```

I reported the issue [here](https://github.com/suiji/Arborist/issues/46). Maybe there is something wrong with my code? Can you help to reproduce/fix this? Are there other quantile regression forest packages (in R), which allow the control of monotonic decreases/increases of the dependent variable for chosen IVs? Thanks!

Comment: Don't know about `Rborist`, but a couple general tips: (a) don't post `rm(list = ls())` on Stack Overflow unless it's crucial to the example - no one wants to run that line accidentally. (b) You don't need `data(iris)` - `iris` is built-in and lazy-loaded by default. (You almost never need `data()`, these days.) (c) You can use `dplyr::select` with `-` as well, you don't need `subset()`. A shorter way to write `x <- subset(temp, select = -c(Sepal.Length))` is `x <- select(temp, -Sepal.Length)`

Comment: Thanks @Gregor - I removed rm(list = ls()). Wow, I did not know that SO and code review are now the same - just kidding your input is appreciated. If you have any input on the actual question that would be even more appreciated! Thanks!